# Using Pygame's pixArray to draw a square

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently creating a drawing program using pygame. Ti draw, I'm using a pixarray. I want the drawing size to be changeable, so I set up my pixarray like this:

```
pixArray[p1+i][p2+i] = mousecolor
pixArray[p1-i][p2+i] = mousecolor
pixArray[p1+i][p2-i] = mousecolor
pixArray[p1-i][p2-i] = mousecolor
```

where i is coming from

```
    for i in range(0,size):
```

Currently, this draws the pixels in a x shape. How do I make it draw a square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a square you need to loop over 2 dimensions, for example like this:

```
for i in range(0, size):
    for j in range(0, size):
        pixArray[p1+i][p2+j] = mousecolor
        pixArray[p1-i][p2+j] = mousecolor
        pixArray[p1+i][p2-j] = mousecolor
        pixArray[p1-i][p2-j] = mousecolor
```

You can't make a quadratic number of points with one linear loop.